# Get center coordinates of map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, bing-maps, virtual-earth

I am using VEMap API. I have the latitude and longitude of the top left point and the bottom right point (bounding box) of a map. I want to get the center point. What is an easy way to do that? I couldn't find a solution by searching on Google.

What I was thinking is that if I can define the map using the two points mentioned above, then I can get the center very easily:

```
// JavaScript code snippet
var center = map.GetCenter();
var lat = center.Latitude;
var lng = center.Longitude;
```

Is there a way to call the constructor of map object and pass the two coordinates I have?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer would be add the latitudes and divide by two, and do the same for longitudes. They are straight lines.

Comment: watch out - they could cross the 180° line

Comment: Theoretically yes, but I am only working with countries where they don't.

Comment: @Bergi, can you please answer my question on the top of this page? I came up with a workaround which works perfectly in my scenario. There won't be ANY cases in which it won't. How is that bad code? When someone is making a simple application to show time on a watch, will one handle a situation where minutes and hours can be in millions or billions?

Comment: No, but his application should be open to show different timezones, even if he is going to ship it only to one country :-)

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't use the `VEMap.GetCenter` method after the map has been constructed? This way regardless of the viewpoint it will be correct. If you're using the default constructor you can pass in your bounding box, and then call getmap after the object is instantiated.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412539.aspx